# How to write a T-SQL Stored Procedure to return data from three database tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have to display data from following three tables ('dbo.BookAuthor' is the mapping table).

[Database Diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jchcuvTURdQUhYQnU2QTB4MlU/view?usp=sharing)

I need to write a stored procedure to retrieve data from a stored procedure and fill that data to a DataGridView as follows.

[DataGridView to display above data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jchcuvTURdYmZSaHVld2tRT3M/view?usp=sharing)

Please help me to write SQL query to retrieve data from Book and Author tables using the intermediate BookAuthor table by matching ID s.

This is how my DB is designed. Book table has a primary key as `Book_ID`.
Author table also has its primary key as `Author_ID`.
Because each Book can be written by multiple Authors, I have placed another table (`BookAuthor` table) to map each Book with it's Author(s).
So, `BookAuthor` table has both `Book_ID` and `Author_ID` as foreign keys from Book table and Author table, including it's own primary key `BookAuthor_ID`.

Can someone tell me the SQL Query for retrieving Book_Title and Author_Name(s) for each Book I have.

Comment: By using three queries. My guess is you want different where predicates but from the lack of detail in your post there is nothing we can do to help here.

Comment: @SeanLange, What details do you want about the problem? Sorry I am a newbee so I am not allowed to include any images in my post. Thats why I attachd some links to show what I want.

Comment: Look at what you posted and ask yourself if you would be able to help. The answer of course is no. All you posted is tables that hold book information. Then you posted an image with three tabs. What is add books? What is delete books? What do you want to show? Take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange, I specifically mentioned that I need to 'display' above data in a 'DataGridView', So I took a snapshot of where and how my DataGridView is placed. You should not have bothered about other tabs. Just wanted to show what must be the format of the dataTable. Thats it. :)

Comment: This must be school work then. Glad you got an answer. I hope it is something you retain and understand because this is basic building block of all queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic SQL.
I recommend you to read an sql tutorial.
What you need is called a `JOIN`.
Try this:

```
SELECT [Name], [Title]
FROM Book 
INNER JOIN BookAuthor ON(Book.Book_Id = BookAuthor.Book_Id)
INNER JOIN Author ON(BookAuthor.Author_Id = Author.Author_Id)
```

Also, for future questions, Please describe your tables as using [DDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) statements, and provide sample data using [DML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766.aspx) statements if needed. desired output is better described in the question's text as a code block. for more information, please read [how to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ah now that is what I'am looking for. Of course I have came across `SQL JOIN`s but the problem was, I didn't know how to `JOIN` three tables at once. :)

Comment: Also, If an answer provided the solution to your problem, please accept it so that other people will know the problem is solved. Welcome to stackoverflow. it's a brave new world out here :-)

Comment: @ZoharPled, How can I accept this as the solution before even trying it out myself? Just be patient man. I am trying to apply your solution, and if it solves my problem, I will definitely mark this as the solution. :)

Comment: You are the one that wrote `that is what I'am looking for.` I assumed you already tested it...

Comment: @ZoharPled, Yes but I didn't say that is the solution. At that moment all I saw is how to JOIN three tables. I meant that. And at this moment, I tried your code and it worked.